# Nested loop using tool in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have a loop I am trying to construct. that is pulling files from different paths. I need to loop these together. Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --mem=110g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12

module load java/17.0.2

for bam in /PATH1/*.sorted.dmark.bam;
do
  java -Xmx110g -jar /PATHtoTOOL/fgbio-2.0.0.jar AnnotateBamWithUmis \
     -i bam \
     -f /PATH2/*_L001_UMI.fastq.gz \ # This is where I need the secodary loop
     -o bam.UMI.bam
done
```

Comment: So like looping over the key/value of an associative array at the same time?

Comment: basically yes. all the samples are in order, I just need to loop through each bam file and the associated UMI file need in -f.

Comment: What does this have to do with _nested_ loops? If you're just changing a prefix and suffix in your input path to generate an output path, there's no nesting needed for that.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to run your Java program a separate time for each combination of files? If that's what you want a nested loop really _is_ the right thing, but it's not clear what specific problem prevented you from creating a nested loop on your own, just by putting a `for fastq in /PATH2/*_L001_UMI.fastq.gz; do` loop inside your existing loop.

Comment: Hi Charles, you are correct, it is option two is what I need. Could you right up an answer for me to look at! I have nested many loops, never using a tool lik this. So this would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate two arrays with the files, walk them by index:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
dmarks=(/PATH1/*.sorted.dmark.bam)
fastqs=(/PATH2/*_L001_UMI.fastq.gz)

if (( ${#dmarks[@]} != ${#fastqs[@]} )) ; then
    echo Different number of files >&2
    exit 1
fi

for (( i=0; i<${#dmarks[@]}; ++i)) ; do
    dmark=${dmarks[i]}
    fastq=${fastqs[i]}
    java -Xmx110g -jar /PATHtoTOOL/fgbio-2.0.0.jar AnnotateBamWithUmis \
        -i "$dmark" \
        -f "$fastq" \
        -o bam.UMI.bam
done
```

Comment: Hi Choroba sor for the tool part of my loop -i would be dmarks and -f would be fastq?

Comment: Updated with the full example.